Fabricjs panel containing text boxes should allow for editing text
I have built a panel using fabricjs that contains a list.

Every item is a text, and each text can be edited. The user can move the entire panel on the canvas. See codepen.
The code allows you to edit items (by double-clicking on them in the example, but mousedown would suffice), but the textboxes do not behave as expected for a fabric.js textbox. The cursor only appears at the beginning or end of the textbox, I cannot position the cursor in the middle of the box.
I simply want the user to be able to edit the text on the textboxes by clicking on them, and at the same time, allow the user to move the panel, but seems I am overcomplicating things.
It seems to me I should not be calling "enterEditing" myself, just let the events reach the textbox, see code:
items.forEach((item) => {
  let text = createTextItem(item.text, currentTop, 10);
  text.on("mousedblclick", function (e) {
    this.enterEditing();
    canvas.add(text).setActiveObject(text);
  });
  texts.push(text);
  currentTop += text.height + 5;
});

Is there an alternative way of doing this?
